# Changing the values of an IBOutlet from another class

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, iboutlet

I'm creating a Calculator app as my first project in Xcode, and I'm trying to implement key pressing functionality. In order to do this, I created a `Global` class which housed all of the code so that both my `NSWindow` class and my `NSViewController` class could access it without errors, since the app hinges on changing the text of an IBOutlet. However the problem is that it returns an `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` with the code I've currently got, and I really don't know how else I could go about doing this:

This is how I access the IBOutlet from the Global class: `viewInstance.configureLabel(newString: newEquationCacheLabel)`

This is what that accesses:

```
@IBOutlet weak private var equationCacheLabel: NSTextField!

func configureLabel(newString: String) {
    equationCacheLabel.stringValue = newString
}
```

And then there's a global instance of my ViewController (declared outside of the class): `let viewInstance = ViewController()`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can it be because the Object is set as private? I'm not really sure but maybe that's why it doesn't find it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who helped, but it turns out that the reason it was returning `nil` was that I was accessing a `nil` version. I was accessing my own version of `ViewController`, which didn't have an initalized version of `equationCacheLabel`. It turned out that if I accessed the `NSViewController` actually being displayed in the app, it worked just fine. This is how I accessed that `NSViewController` (note that I'm creating an OS X/macOS Swift app, this will not work in an i/tv/watchOS app or an Objective-C app):

`(NSApplication.shared().keyWindow?.contentViewController as! ViewController)`

That will get you access to the ViewController currently being displayed, and any IBActions/Outlets you need.

Comment: Are you able to explain this a little more, and maybe add some example code?  I'm trying to access an IBOutlet in swift 5 on macOS, and this is the closest I have come to finding an answer on how to achieve this.